# Proving $|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|^3 =(r^2+s^2-2\cdot r\cdot s\cdot \cos(\theta))^{3/2} $

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I want to prove
$$
|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|^3 =(r^2+s^2-2\cdot r\cdot s\cdot \cos(\theta))^{3/2}
$$
where $r=|\vec{r}|$.
but I have problems because
$$
(r^2+s^2-2\cdot r\cdot s\cdot \cos(\theta))^{3/2}=(r^2+s^2-\vec{r}\cdot \vec{s})^{3/2}=((\vec{r}-\vec{s})^2)^{3/2}=(\vec{r}-\vec{s})^3
$$
I hope someone can help me. thank you

Comment: What does $(\vec{r}-\vec{s})^2$ even mean?  How do you square a vector?

Comment: I suspect that your equations are missing a few $\bigl | \cdots \bigr |$ symbols.

Comment: In the right hand side....the r and s refer to the magnitudes of the vector. And the dot product between vectors r and s is defined to be as $\lvert r\rvert\lvert s\rvert\cos(\theta)$

Comment: @randall I think he means the square of the magnitude. Or the dot product of the vector with itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard derivation.  Start with the fact that $|\vec{v}|^2 = \vec{v}  \cdot \vec{v}$ applied to $\vec{v} = \vec{r} - \vec{s}$ to get
$$
|\vec{r} - \vec{s}|^2 = (\vec{r}-\vec{s}) \cdot (\vec{r}-\vec{s}).
$$
Now expand the dot product to get
$$
|\vec{r} - \vec{s}|^2=r^2 + s^2 - 2\vec{r}\cdot\vec{s} = r^2+s^2 -2rs\cos(\theta).
$$
Now take the square root of both sides, then cube. Done.